# Grunt build products

Tags: javascript, web-applications, gruntjs

When building the front-end portion of a web application with Grunt, should build and dist folders be used to organize build products? and if so, what build products should go in each?

Comment: It's up to you. `build` and `dist` while sort of a convention, are not required.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, but it's convention which you should respect to.

**Writing an Awesome Build Script with Grunt**
http://www.sitepoint.com/writing-awesome-build-script-grunt/

**Configuring tasks - Grunt: The JavaScript Task Runner**
http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks

Can helps ;-)